# Mapserver weird output of REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1

Tags: apache, ubuntu, mapserver, umn-mapserver

Once I use REQUEST=GetCapabilities&SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1 in my browser with the mapserv I get the following:

> $ cat ~/Downloads/ms

```
ELF>�@@!@8  @@@@��888�� �� � �� �� �   TTTDDP�tdLLQ�tdR�td�� � xx/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2GNUGNU��@%(/���|jx(�|�C�CE��j�|2b������
                                  :�
                                    �K���qX����
                                                ��  є�8����l��w�=�R ���' �"����C �`l ����!3��  �  �e�   g  a
 ibmapserver.so.2_Jv_RegisterClasses_ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable__gmon_start___ITM_registerTMCloneTablemsIO_installHandlersmsResetErrorListmsFreeMapServObjmsDebugloadParamsmsCGIWriteErrormsGetVersionmsCGIWriteLogmsSetupmsGetGlobalDebugLevelmsCGIDispatchRequestmsCGILoadMapmsAllocMapServObjmsCleanupmsIO_setHeaderEnabledlibfcgi.so.0FCGI_AcceptFCGI_freadFCGI_fwrite_fcgi_sFlibc.so.6fflushexitstrncmpsignalputsputchargetpidputenvstdoutgettimeofday__cxa_finalize__libc_start_main_edata__bss_start_end/usr/lib� � � � � � � � �  _used__libc_csu_fini__data_startmsCleanupOnSignalGLIBC_2.2.5�ui   �����  � � � 


        ( 0 8 @ H P X ` h p x � � � � �  � !� "� #� $H�H�E H��t�+H���5 �% @�% h������% h������% h������% h������% h������% h������% h������% h�p����% �`����%� h    �P����%� h
�@����%� h
          �0����%� h
�����%� h�����%� h������%� h������%z h������%r h������%j h������%b h������%Z h������%R h������%J h�p����%B h�`����%: h�P����%2 h�@����%* h�0����%" h� ����% h����AWAVAUATI��U��SH��x�������t1��=��������1��Q����L�����v
H���w�����2�H�=�H��L����H�L9�u�H�5��
 H�L$@H�L$`H�PH�D$(H�� H�D$hH�T$HH�H�T$PL�������������c������vRH��1�������H*L$�H*T��H*D$H�=o�^�^�X��H*
H�����������}-�t����}h�j����}�`���H�=q������                                                                    $X�\�����������1��������E<v���}��H�5��
�r���H�=�����H�=��z���H�=��n���H�=��b���H�=�V���1�������<n�^����}h�T����}�J���1�E1�����������H�=������H�;����������@�����L�H��E1�1�1�1�D�pL�������A�GH�H�߃x����%���H��H�C����H~
��H*D$PH�=D�^�X��H*L$0X�\����1�H���U���H���=������������K���H�������H�,
                                                                              H�8�D���1��}���H���U����L���A������D������55
                                                                                                                             H�=K��1�������
lH�=�����@����f.�DH�                                                                                                                       ����1�I��^H��H���PTL��H�
 H�=
 UH)�H��H�w]�H��
 H��t�]�@H��
 H�=�
 UH)�H��H��H��H��?H�H��u]�H�G
 H��t�]H���@�=m
 u'H�=7
 UH��t
      H�=J
 ������h���]�D
 ��fffff.�H�=� t&H�
 H��tUH�=� H����]�W�����K���f.��1�H�1�1�������L���1������DH�H��Hc�H��������H�@H�H��Hc�H��������H�@AWA��AVI��AUI��ATL�%� UH�-� SL)�1�H��H������H��t�L��L��D��A��H��H9�u�H�[]A\A]A^A_�ff.���H�H��REQUEST_METHOD=GET--helpOptions :fcgiCGI Request %d on process %d
QUERY_STRING=Usage: mapserv [--help] [-v] [-nh] [QUERY_STRING=value]  -h, --help              Display this help message.  -v                      Display version and exit.  -nh                     Suppress HTTP headers in CGI mode.  QUERY_STRING=value      Set the QUERY_STRING in GET request mode.mapserv request processing time (msLoadMap not incl.): %.3fs
mapserv total execution time: %.3fs
��.A;������������h ����@����`��������@�����zRx
                                                         �����*zRx
                                                                           �$ ����FJ
\`���Dth���D4�����GBBB �B(�D0�C8�D�D�8���eBEE �E(�H0�H8�M@l8A0A(B BB �?;*3$"DX���
                                                                                        `�����S�
�� � ���o���                                                                                      �
�
  � ��

�   ���o���o
���o���oZ
���o� &6FVfv����&6FVfv���  41ff45f23492ece94952837828d17cc05e8552.debug`�7�.shstrtab.interp.note.ABI-tag.note.gnu.build-id.gnu.hash.dynsym.dynstr.gnu.version.gnu.version_r.rela.dyn.rela.plt.init.text.fini.rodata.eh_frame_hdr.eh_frame.init_array.fini_array.jcr.dynamic.got.data.bss.gnu_debuglink
                                                                                                                                                88TT !tt$4���o��>
           ���F���N���oZ
Z
d[���o

 j

t�
     �
      �
       ~��y����B��� ��L�PPT�� �� �� �� � �� ��      � 4H �
```

This is the first time I get something like this with Mapserver, I installed 7.0.7 in Linux mint:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep mapserver
ii  cgi-mapserver                                               7.0.7-1~trusty3                                      amd64        CGI executable for MapServer
ii  libmapserver2                                               7.0.7-1~trusty3                                      amd64        Shared library for MapServer
ii  mapserver-bin                                               7.0.7-1~trusty3                                      amd64        MapServer utilities
```

Any support is welcomed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Add the NextGIS ppa (https://launchpad.net/~nextgis/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and upgrade the mapserver version:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep mapserv 
ii  cgi-mapserver                                               7.2.1+2-0trusty1                                     amd64        CGI executable for MapServer
ii  libmapserver1                                               7.2.1+2-0trusty1                                     amd64        Shared library for MapServer
ii  mapserver-bin                                               7.2.1+2-0trusty1                                     amd64        MapServer utilities
```